# add item from one list to n number of items to another list

Tags: python

I have a short list of device ID's as:

```
   dev_id=['208', '209']
```

and I have another list of photos for each of this device

```
  files=['pic1.png', 'pic2.png', 'pic3.png', 'pic4.png', 'pic5.png', 'pic6.png']
```

how can i add a device id for each n pictures in the files list? For example if i want to add to 3 elements of the files list, so that i have

```
  n_files=['208_pic1.png', '208_pic2.png', '208_pic3.png', '209_pic4.png', '209_pic5.png', '209_pic6.png']
```

I'm quite new in python and still don't really know how to work properly with lists

I guess I need to do something like that

```
  k=0
  for i = 1:length(dev_id)
      
      for j=1:3
          n_files=dev_id(i)+n_files(i+?)
          k+1
      end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have one id for each file (*.png) ? If not how do you know to each file corresponds to each id ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve with a list comprehension like this. However!! Note that the maths to calculate `dev_id` index needs to ensure we don't increment that index and end up in an array index out of bound error.

```py
# List comprehension enumerating files, and using integer division to specify dev_id index
# However, note that the math to calc index of dev_id needs to ensure that we don't run into 
# array index out of bound
new_list = [dev_id[i//3] + "_" + filename for i, filename in enumerate(files)]

# Using a regular loop to achieve the same
new_list = list()
index = 0
for i in range(len(files)):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
        index += 1
    new_list.append(dev_id[index] + "_" +files[i])
```

outputs

```
['208_pic1.png', '208_pic2.png', '208_pic3.png', '209_pic4.png', '209_pic5.png', '209_pic6.png']
```

Comment: `devid + filename` --> `"_".join(devid, filename)`

Comment: Thanks @tbjorch, but here you add item from dev_id to all items of files, but I only need to let's say first 3, not all of them. Also I tried on a bigger list and it gives some strange results.

Comment: @NPR you didn't explain in your question how you choose that `n`

Comment: n can be anything. in my example n=3, so I only want to add first element of dev_id to 3 elements of files. Next 3 elements of files should have a prefix of second element of dev_id

Comment: `"_".join((devid, filename))`

Comment: @NPR updated now. However as Tomerikoo mentions you would need to ensure that you don't end up with an IndexError because you go out of bound on `dev_id`

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried this code as well and it works like a charm. I still need some time to understand every step. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use list comprehensions, use a nested for loop

```py
new_list = []
for ids in dev_id:
    for file in files:
        new_list.append(ids+'_'+file)
```

Answer (score 0):

To spread the device ids over evenly over the files, you would need to determine the size of chunks of files that would be on the same device (in this case 6Files/2id = 3 files per id).

```
dev_id = ['208', '209']
files  = ['pic1.png', 'pic2.png', 'pic3.png', 'pic4.png', 
         'pic5.png', 'pic6.png']

chunk   = (len(files)-1)//len(dev_id)+1
n_files = [f"{d}_{f}" for i,d in enumerate(dev_id) 
                      for f in files[chunk*i:][:chunk]]

['208_pic1.png', '208_pic2.png', '208_pic3.png', '209_pic4.png', 
   '209_pic5.png', '209_pic6.png']
```

If you don't care which file receives which id and also to get a more even spread, you could use zip with a cycle on device ids:

```
from itertools import cycle
n_files = [f"{d}_{f}" for d,f in zip(cycle(dev_id),files)]

['208_pic1.png', '209_pic2.png', '208_pic3.png', '209_pic4.png', 
 '208_pic5.png', '209_pic6.png']
```

The second approach will avoid having one device with a very small number of files in case where the ratio of files to devices is not flush:

For example:

```
dev_id = ['208', '209', '210']
files  = ['pic1.png', 'pic2.png', 'pic3.png', 'pic4.png', 
          'pic5.png', 'pic6.png','pic7.png']

n_files = [f"{d}_{f}" for d,f in zip(cycle(dev_id),files)]

# 3x208, 2x209, 2x210
['208_pic1.png', '209_pic2.png', '210_pic3.png', '208_pic4.png', 
 '209_pic5.png', '210_pic6.png', '208_pic7.png']


chunk   = (len(files)-1)//len(dev_id)+1
n_files = [f"{d}_{f}" for i,d in enumerate(dev_id) 
                      for f in files[chunk*i:][:chunk]]

# 3x208, 3x209, 1x210
['208_pic1.png', '208_pic2.png', '208_pic3.png', '209_pic4.png',
 '209_pic5.png', '209_pic6.png', '210_pic7.png']
```

Comment: Thanks your code works very well, but actually I know exactly the chunk of files I want to append each device ID. Thanks for the help!